# JEE Servlet / JS: document.cookie not returning same thing between Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, jakarta-ee, cookies

I have a problem getting a cookie value from my response in IE. On Chrome, everything works fine, I have a token which is named `fileDownloadToken` and I set it in my Java controller like this:

```
String tokenValue = value;
response.addCookie(new Cookie("fileDownloadToken",tokenValue);
```

With my JS I get it with just a:

```
var cookieList = document.cookie;
```

And then I split it to search for the cookie I want.

The problem comes with IE, I can see that it is in my response header :

[image: ReponseHeader in IE]

But when I do a `console.log(document.cookie)`, I can't see it. So obviously it's not a problem of `HttpOnly` because otherwise I wouldn't be able to see it in Chrome. I've also tried setting the cookie in server side using:

```
final StringBuilder cookie =
    new StringBuilder("fileDownloadToken=" + new StringBuilder(tokenValue) + "; ");
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie.toString());
```

But It doesn't work either for IE (works for Chrome too though).

I really have no idea what to try now. Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: I have in my JS a function that regularly check for the cookies:

```
var fileDownloadCheckTimer;

function checkDownloadToken() {
  fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
    var cookieValue = getCookie("fileDownloadToken")
    if (cookieValue == token)
      clearTimer();
  }, 2000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may concern, I solved the problem with just adding

`cookie.addPath("/");`

Cheers